# Speech/ Music classification

Tags: audio, signal-processing, speech

I want to determine which part of audio file contain speech or music.

I hope someone has a made something like this or can tell me where to start.
Can you please suggest some method/tutorial for doing the same.

Thank you.

Comment: how did you finally achieve it? 6 years later, I am trying to solve same problem. I want to find out which segment has speech and which segment has music in a recorded audio.  :(

Comment: We got some success with Kaldi speech recognition toolkit. Here, you can train your ML speech/music models and used them for classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of prior art in this area, but I'd suggest browsing through some of [Dan Ellis's](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/) papers. The slides for [this talk](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/talks/ASA-austin-2003-11.pdf) has some good background.  In short it's all down to picking the right feature vectors.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [the pyAudioAnalysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/)  python library. Among others, it has a pre-trained speech-music classifier and two segmentation-classification methods (one based on fix-sized windows and another based on HMMs).

You can extract speech and music parts of an audio recording quite easily, e.g.:

`from pyAudioAnalysis import audioSegmentation as aS
[flagsInd, classesAll, acc] = aS.mtFileClassification("data/scottish.wav",       "data/svmSM", "svm", True, 'data/scottish.segments')`

with a result as the one in [this image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/mtFileClassificationExample.png)

Comment: Sir, could you please take a look at this: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45223/how-to-detect-and-remove-dial-tone-and-ivrs-voice-etc-from-the-beginning-of-an-a